# Tortoise SVN Version 1.7.7.17493 - show log not working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

With subversion when i commit (with log message) all works well and when try 'show log' throws a windows saying want to go offine ?  where as i can browse repository.

Comment: The latest version is currently 1.6.6

Comment: Why has this been down-voted? It actually helped me solve the exact same problem.

Comment: Where is this Authz file located?.

Comment: +1 .. added a couple tags so others can find the question easier, and another answer since the currently accepted answer did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok got it fixed.  My authz file was missing * = r

Comment: I had the same authz file problem... I`m glad I checked this site.

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me when Tortoise SVN > Show Log .. crashed and kept saying "Not Responding."  It was either due to clicking "Clear" on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th button.  Because I tried the 5th button (Authentication Data > "Clear" button) and did not resolve my issue.  After resolving this issue, I can now see all revisions when choosing the "Show Log" option and the dialog doesn't crash.

**Solution:**

Right click any file in Windows (XP in my case) > TortoiseSVN > Settings > Saved Data > I clicked "Clear" for all "Clear" buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This also helped me to look into the permission issue. But it looks like the server may have been busy returning after timeout to display this message. I had the user retry after a few hours since at the time, there was some testing going on on that server.